# Cancel a keystroke in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, textbox, keypress, keystroke

Is is possible (cross-browser compatible) to **CANCEL** a keystroke after a user has made it (for example on a textbox)

The code I currently use edits the textbox value after the keystroke has been displayed:

```
$('.number').keypress(function() {
    this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9\.]/g, '');
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**SOLVED (AND UPDATED)**

Apologies, I didnt test the most obvious option - which worked:

```
$('.number').keypress(function(event) {
    return /[0-9\.]/.test(String.fromCharCode(event.keyCode));
});
```

Comment: +1 This is the way to do it if you don't want to briefly see the prohibited entry. You could clean it up a little using `test()`, like this: `/[^0-9\.]/.test(String.fromCharCode(event.keyCode))`. No replace or assignment is needed since you are doing `return false;`. No need for the `g` global identifier either, since you're testing a single key event.

Comment: Thanks, I have updated my answer with your suggestion with one small change - removing the carrat (^) from the regex as that would invert the result of the test :) Much appreciated!

Answer (score 4):

```
$('.number').keypress(function() {
    if ( this.value == 'foobar' ){
        // "Cancel" keystroke
        return false;
    }
    this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9\.]/g, '');
});
```

Comment: This wouldn't work. You would need to test for prohibited values in `this.value` using a regular expression. You're testing for an exact match against the entirety of `this.value`

Comment: Actually, if the `if()` statement ever did return `true`, the `replace()` wouldn't fire. Since you're testing against `this.value`, that is a crucial part.